# For loop only prints out when combined with a character other than space or empty string

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to print from an array of ten thousand using a for loop and it won't print unless I include another character in the print statement

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] arr = new int[10000];

    for(int i = arr.length-1; i>0;i--) {
        arr[i]=rand.nextInt(1000);
        System.out.print("");
    }
    for(int i = arr.length-1; i>0;i--) {
        System.out.print("_"+arr[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("end program");
```

the output looks like this

145_126_739_226_245 
end program

otherwise when their is just a space in the string it doesn't print out anything

```
package Lab7A;

import java.util.Random;

public class Lab7A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] arr = new int[10000];

        for(int i = arr.length-1; i>0;i--) {
            arr[i]=rand.nextInt(1000);
            System.out.print("");
        }
        for(int i = arr.length-1; i>0;i--) {
            System.out.print(" "+arr[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("end program");




    }
}
```

The Output is just
end program

Comment: do you use an IDE, for performance reasons IDE consoles may omit if a line is too long. try running the program from linux/windows terminal

Comment: Printing a 10000+ char one-liner is a bit radical I'd say. Try adding a few newlines here and there, your horizontal scrollbar will thank you

Comment: re: Yakup's and Perdi's comments — You could try adding a newline every so often. After `System.out.print(" "+arr[i]);` put in `if (i % 10 == 0) System.out.println();` which would start a new line every 10 iterations. When I run your 2nd block (the whole "Lab7A" program) on the command-line I do get the expected output — one very long line with space-separated numbers, ending with "end program"

Comment: It's more of a question of why does this occur because the underscored code prints out the whole output while the one with a space doesnt print at all

Comment: Are you experiencing this within Eclipse? If yes:

EDIT:

Go to Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console
Uncheck "Limit Console Output" (Alternatively you can increase the Console buffer size.)

Comment: _"It's more of a question of why does this occur"_ — that's why Yakup asked about an IDE; the _why_ could be because your IDE is dropping the too-long line. You could test if that's the case by outputting a newline every _**n**_ iterations. Just running your Lab7A program on my own machine, using just the terminal (command line), it produced the expected output so it's unlikely that it's a problem with the code, more likely that it's a problem with the environment.